# Proof of p^2=p for projections

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

Sorry, it should be really simple, but i forgot how do prove it.
If we define a projection $p$ onto subspace $U$ of a finite-dimensional space $V$ by these 2 properties: Image($p$)=$U$ and $p_U$ is identity, then why do we have $p^2=p$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $P^2=P$ is usually the *definition*. Pause and think; $P_U$ is the identity - will future compositions then change anything?

Comment: It can be shown that $\ker(p)\cap U=0$. Therefore by the rank-nullity theorem, $\ker(p)\oplus U=V$. Now by the linearity of $p$ it suffices to prove the equality $p^2=p$ separately on $\ker(p)$ and on $U$.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!

Comment: I believe what FShrike is saying is this: $u=P(x)\in U$ for all $x\in V$. Since $P_U$ is the identity, $P(u)=u$ for all $u\in U$. Therefore, $P(P(x))=P(u)=u=P(x)$. That is, $P^2(x)=P(x)$ for all $x\in V$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the image of the transformation is $U$ this mean that for all $v$ in $V$ we have $p(v)=u$ for some $u$ in $U$. Since $p$ restricted to $U$ is the identity we have $p(u)=u$. Putting these together we have $p(p(v))=p(u)=u$ so $p^2=p$.